# Chewy Bechamel while making Moussaka

Tags: greek-cuisine

After making my moussaka from a recipe online I couldn't help but notice that the bechamel didn't bubble when it was in the oven and when it was done the bechamel became chewy. What could be the reason for this?

**Recipe for bechamel:**
335ml milk (although I used this initially I found the bechamel to be VERY thick when making roux so I added a tea cup of milk while making the roux)

1 small onion

salt and pepper, to taste

35g butter

35g flour

50g mozzarella cheese, for topping

Comment: The length limits aren't just there to be weird, they're there to encourage you to do things like putting a summary of your actual question in the title.

Comment: It may have been the mozzarella. When traditional Greek moussaka is topped with grated cheese, it is usually a harder, aged variety, such as Kefalotyri or Parmigiano-Reggiano. To thin the bechamel with additional milk, after the roux is complete, is fine. The roux should be very thick, as it's only flour and butter. It thins when the liquid is added, then thickens again as it simmers. However, if your bechamel was too thin and the cheese melted into it, that may account for the chewy result.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's what happened as I could taste what appeared to be just a layer of cheese, which I suppose was due to the cheese melting

Comment: But, unfortunately I don't have access to these type of cheeses. Could I use some other more commercially available cheese?

Comment: Are cheddar or Gouda viable options?

Comment: I think they're too soft; what hard, aged cheeses are available to you (and where are you located ... city/country)?

Comment: India, we are big on cottage cheese :) I know that will not work

Comment: I guess I am screwed in the cheese department

Comment: You're not; omit the cheese; it's fabulous without.

Comment: Read this article http://www.indiatimes.com/culture/food/9-cheese-farms-you-didnt-know-existed-in-india-231182.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may have been the mozzarella. When traditional Greek moussaka is topped with grated cheese, it is usually a harder, aged variety, such as Kefalotyri or Parmigiano-Reggiano. To thin the bechamel with additional milk, after the roux is complete, is fine. The roux should be very thick, as it's only flour and butter. It thins when the liquid is added, then thickens again as it simmers. However, if your bechamel was too thin and the cheese melted into it, that may account for the chewy result.